# How to check if all elements in a tuple or list are in another?

Tags: python, list, set, tuples

For example, I want to check every elements in tuple `(1, 2)` are in tuple `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`.
I don't think use loop is a good way to do it, I think it could be done in one line.

Comment: Are the tuples sorted?

Comment: Are you only asking about **the case where all elements are integers? and moreover, sorted in-order? (so that the order of the tuple doesn't matter?)** Do you want to return True or False for testing (2,1) in (5,3,1,4,2)? Can you please show several more examples with expect output value?

Comment: And if the all elements are contiguous integers, you can use a data structure like [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice) which only needs to test its lower- and upper-bound (`start`, `stop` and `step`, you don't even need a tuple/set. Or `itertools.islice`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [`set.issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=issubset#set.issubset) or [`set.issuperset`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=issubset#set.issuperset) to check if every element in one tuple or list is in other.

```
>>> tuple1 = (1, 2)
>>> tuple2 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> set(tuple1).issubset(tuple2)
True
>>> set(tuple2).issuperset(tuple1)
True
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you want this: ( Use [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) )

```
>>> all(i in (1,2,3,4,5) for i in (1,2))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is specifically targeted at tuples/lists and not sets, I would assume you include cases where elements are repeated and the number of repetition matters. For example `(1, 1, 3)` is in `(0, 1, 1, 2, 3)`, but `(1, 1, 3, 3)` is not.

```
import collections

def contains(l1, l2):
    l1_cnt = set(collections.Counter(l1).items())
    l2_cnt = set(collections.Counter(l2).items())

    return l2_cnt <= l1_cnt

# contains((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2)) returns True
# contains((0, 1, 1, 2, 3), (1, 1, 3)) returns True
# contains((0, 1, 1, 2, 3), (1, 1, 3, 3)) returns False
```

Answer (score -2):

Another alternative would be to create a simple function when the set doesn't come to mind.

```
def tuple_containment(a,b):
    ans = True
    for i in iter(b):
        ans &= i in a
    return ans
```

> Now simply test them

```
>>> tuple_containment ((1,2,3,4,5), (1,2))
True
>>> tuple_containment ((1,2,3,4,5), (2,6))
False
```

Comment: And I clearly mentioned that mine is when the _obvious doesn't come to mind_

Comment: What does `tuple_checker` do? Check for equality, containment, or just whether they are tuples?