# How to use Python 'in' operator to check my list/tuple contains each of the integers 0, 1, 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, contains

How do I use the Python `in` operator to check my list/tuple `sltn` contains each of the integers 0, 1, and 2?

I tried the following, why are they both wrong:

```
# Approach 1
if ("0","1","2") in sltn:
     kwd1 = True

# Approach 2
if any(item in sltn for item in ("0", "1", "2")):
     kwd1 = True
```

---

Update: why did I have to convert `("0", "1", "2")` into either the tuple `(1, 2, 3)`? or the list `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: Needs editing cannot understand

Comment: But `("0","1","2")` *isn't* in `[0, 1, 2]`...

Comment: 1. Items being in a list is not the same as the tuple of those items being in the list. 2. strings are not numbers.

Comment: `if all(x in sltn for x in ("0","1","2")): `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python how to check all elements in a tuple are in another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34468983/in-python-how-to-check-all-elements-in-a-tuple-are-in-another)

Comment: Regarding your edit: you forgot the conversion to integer, see my answer.

Comment: Other comments have pointed this out, but could this be a typo: `[0, 1, 2]`? Did you mean to type `["0", "1", "2"]`. If slnt is `[0, 1, 2]`, you need to change `if any(item in sltn for item in ("0", "1", "2")):` to `if any(item in sltn for item in (0, 1, 2)):` since a list/tuple of ints is not the same as one of strings.

Comment: You're confusing integers 0,1,2 with strings "0","1","2". You're also confusing tuples `(...)` with lists `[...]`, but here that doesn't matter, list and tuple are both collections and support `in` operator. (But please don't call them arrays, those are different again). You're also confusing `if x in y` with `if y in x` and `all(xx in y for xx in x)` and that does matter hugely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if ("0","1","2") in sltn
```

You are trying to check whether the `sltn` list contains the tuple `("0","1","2")`, which it does not. (It contains 3 integers)

But you can get it done using [#all()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) :

```
sltn = [1, 2, 3] # list
tab = ("1", "2", "3") # tuple

print(all(int(el) in sltn for el in tab)) # True
```

Comment: How do I test if it has those units ? Sorry, I am not very advanced at python.

Comment: to test for every member: `inside = True;for i in ("0","1","2"): if(i in sltn): continue;else: inside = False;break;`

Comment: I'm really surprised that everyone has come up with this solution. Iteration for comparison is not valid. It is a very bad practice. What if there were a million rows in the list? The user should sit and wait for half hour?

Answer (score 22):

Using the `in` keyword is a shorthand for calling an object's `__contains__` method.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> 2 in a
True
>>> a.__contains__(2)
True
```

Thus, `("0","1","2") in [0, 1, 2]` asks whether the tuple `("0", "1", "2")` is *contained* in the list `[0, 1, 2]`. The answer to this question if `False`. To be `True`, you would have to have a list like this:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, ("0","1","2")]
>>> ("0","1","2") in a
True
```

Please also note that the elements of your tuple are strings. You probably want to check whether any or all of the elements in your tuple - *after converting these elements to integers* - are contained in your list.

To check whether all elements of the tuple (as integers) are contained in the list, use

```
>>> sltn = [1, 2, 3]
>>> t = ("0", "2", "3")
>>> set(map(int, t)).issubset(sltn)
False
```

To check whether any element of the tuple (as integer) is contained in the list, you can use

```
>>> sltn_set = set(sltn)
>>> any(int(x) in sltn_set for x in t)
True
```

and make use of the lazy evaluation `any` performs.

Of course, if your tuple contains strings for no particular reason, just use
`(1, 2, 3)` and omit the conversion to int.

Comment: In fact this is the only answer about the `in` operator. +1.

Comment: You should use `issubset` or `issuperset` as show in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34469004/3100115) instead of using a for loop. `set(map(int, t)).issubset(sltn)`

Comment: Iteration for comparison is not a valid solution. It would take half an hour if the list contained a million entries!

Comment: @PouriaHadjibagheri and user3100115 you are right, updated.

Comment: @timgeb, although clearly each class can define its own `__contains__`, it seems a bit inconsistent that `'abc'.__contains__('ab')` is `True` but `[1,2,3].__contains__([1,2])` is `False` (and similarly for tuples). Is there a rationale for this disparity?

Comment: @alancalvitti for strings, `__contains__` answers the substring-question. For lists, `__contains__` answers whether its argument is an element of the list. `[1, 2]` is not an element of the list `[1, 2, 3]`. (`[1, 2]` would be an element of the list `[[1, 2], 3]`, for example.)

Comment: @timgeb, understood, but still seems asymmetrical, like `ab` should also be an element of `['ab','c']`

Comment: @alancalvitti `'ab' in ['ab', 'c']` is `True`.

Comment: @timgeb, my fault, I considered the wrong branch. It's asymmetrical b/c `'ab' in 'ab'+'c'` is `True` while the analogous `[1,2] in [1,2]+[3]` is `False`

Comment: @alancalvitti Strings have different use cases than lists. Having their methods behave exactly the same would be a very foolish kind of consistency. You can call the design asymmetrical, but you should be glad it is.

Comment: @timgeb, understood, but they are both `isinstance(arg, collections.Iterable)` which is how some problems arise.

Answer (score 1):

To check whether your sequence contains *all* of the elements you want to check, you can use a generator comprehension in a call to `all`:

```
if all(item in sltn for item in ("0", "1", "2")):
    ...
```

If you're fine with either of them being inside the list, you can use `any` instead:

```
if any(item in sltn for item in ("0", "1", "2")):
    ...
```

Comment: @G.Armstrong ... and the result is that none of "0", "1", or "2" is an element of `sltn` because `sltn` is a list of the integers 0, 1, and 2  - it does not contain any strings. This answer is correct, but I thought that I'd point that out to the OP in case they try it out and don't get the expected result

Comment: Seriously? You wanna iterate through the entire list every time? That's very inefficient. What if the list contained a million entries?

Comment: Membership tests are linear in lists, correct. If there are a million entries, they should probably use a set instead.

Comment: They should use `set` in the beginning. It's a bad practice to use iterations for comparison, regardless of the length. Now I understand that people may very well do that, but that doesn't make it right!

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want waste time and iterate through all the data in your list, as widely suggested around here, you can do as follows:

```
a = ['1', '2', '3']
b = ['4', '3', '5']

test = set(a) & set(b)
if test:
    print('Found it. Here it is: ', test)
```

Of course, you can do `if set(a) & set(b)`. I didn't do that for demonstration purposes. Note that you shouldn't replace `&` with `and`. They are two substantially different operators.

The above code displays:

```
Found it. Here it is:  {'3'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding another variation,
Prints the index of different values and the values themselves.

```
tuple1 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6]

print(type(tuple1))
print(type(list1))

for a, b in zip(list1, tuple1):
    if a != b:
       print(f'index {list1.index(a)} in list1 is different from index {tuple1.index(b)} in tuple1')
       
S1 = set(list1)
S2 = set(tuple1)
difference = list(S1.symmetric_difference(S2))
print(f'The values of symmetric difference between two sets is {difference}')
```

produces,

```
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'list'>
index 3 in list1 is different from index 3 in tuple1
The values of symmetric difference between two sets is [0, 4]

[Program finished]
```