# iterating through a dataframe column to see if individual cell value is in a list of file paths

Tags: pandas, list, loops

I have a list of shapefile paths (sf_list) and I'm using a nested for loop to iterate through the list and a dataframe (df) to see if a value in the row of a column (name) of that dataframe is in that path, and if it is, append that list value to that row of the dataframe in a new column of the dataframe (sf_path). This is what I have now:

```
for sf in sf_list:
    for row in df.iterrows():
        df.loc[df['name'].isin(sf),'sf_path'] = [sf]
```

The script runs but the new column is empty.  The list is populated with all of the paths I need and the column of that dataframe contains specific text that is in the path I went the path to populate in that row of the new column. Any direction appreciated.

---

UPDATE:

Alright now I have:

```
for sf in sf_list:  
    for row in dlrules_df.iterrows():  
        dlrules_df.loc[dlrules_df['dl_foldername'] in sf, 'sf_path'] = sf
```

Error returned:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not Series
```

Comment: I think you might have gotten the wrong impression regarding the usage of [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html). What you probably want to do is to check if the value of the 'Name' column against the list of paths. And if it is found, you append the path to the new 'sf_path' column, right? You probably want to use [in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302215/python-in-operator#35302442) instead

Comment: UPDATE:

Alright now I have:

for sf in sf_list:
for row in dlrules_df.iterrows():
dlrules_df.loc[dlrules_df['dl_foldername'] in sf, 'sf_path'] = sf

error returned:

TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not Series

Answer (score 0):

Can you give this a try? `apply` isn't recommended but it has become quite a habit for me. Would like to spend more time to give you a more efficient solution but it's already bedtime here and this popped out off the back of my head.

```
sf = [list_of_folder_paths]
dlrules_df.loc[:, 'dl_foldername'].apply(lambda x: sf[sf.index(x)] if x in sf else None)
```

**PS:** Not tested, so it may break somewhere but I hope it gives you some idea.

Comment: so that runs, but it doesn't create a new column ("sf_path") that appends the folder path to the dataframe that matches the substring of what's in "dl_foldername"

Comment: @MattSloane You just have to assign it to a new column if that's what you need. ```dlrules_df['sf_path'] = dlrules_df.loc[:, 'dl_foldername'].apply(lambda x: sf[sf.index(x)] if x in sf else None)```